# How to scale the imageBrush of the background of an user control?

Tags: wpf, image, background, user-controls

I have a user control in which I want to add an image as background. I am using this code:

```
<UserControl.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="x:\myLogo.png"/>
</UserControl.Background>
```

The problem is that I don't find the way to scale the image, because it fills the user control and doesn't keep the proportions. I cannot find any way to scale and set another properties of the image, except for the opacity.

So, how I could scale and set the fill options of the image?

Thanks.

Comment: It has a Stretch property, and also Viewbox and Viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ImageBrush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush(v=vs.110).aspx) has the `Stretch` property to define how to fit the content using the [Stretch enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Describes how content is resized to fill its allocated space

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="../Image.jpg"/>
```

[image: No stretch property set]

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="../Image.jpg" Stretch="None"/>
```

[image: Stretch None]

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="../Image.jpg" Stretch="Uniform"/>
```

[image: Stretch Uniform]

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="../Image.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
```

[image: Stretch UniformToFill]

Further cropping, shaping or scaling adjustments can be done by using the [Viewbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush.viewbox(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Viewport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush.viewport(v=vs.110).aspx) properties like described in [this tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0470__Windows-Presentation-Foundation/UsingViewboxandViewport.htm).